# implementing a login with facebook button in asp.net mobile

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mobile

There is something very obvious that I'm missing.  I've implemented the Log in with Facebook tutorial from [asp.net](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/using-oauth-providers-with-mvc), then I created a mobile MVC 4 web site.

I created an AuthConfig which calls:

```
OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterFacebookClient(
    appId: "...",
    appSecret: "...");
```

then, in Views/Home/Login.cshtml, I created a button

```
 <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log in with Facebook", "FacebookLogin")</li>
```

and lastly, in /Controllers/HomeController.cs I added:

```
    public ActionResult FacebookLogin()
    {
        return new FacebookLoginResult(this.Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback"));
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
    {
        AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
        if (!result.IsSuccessful)
        {
     ...
```

(For the sake of completeness, FacebookLogin result is a class that inherits from ActionResult and calls

```
    OAuthWebSecurity.RequestAuthentication("facebook", "/Home/ExternalLoginCallback");
```

in the ExecuteResult() override.  When I step through it, I see the button being pressed, I see ExecuteResult() being called, but it never makes it to ExternalLoginCallback().  The whole process simply errors out.  There is likely something very easy and very obvious that I'm missing, but barring that, how can I enable more extended logging to see where it is breaking down?  I'm using IIS Express for both the MVC site that worked and the MVC mobile site that doesn't.

Thanks!

Comment: Does it error out on Facebook's side?  Do you get an error on Facebook, or from your app?

Comment: It's difficult for me to say since I'm new to MVC, but I'm pretty sure it is on my side. Facebook tends to show an error page with a specific error, all I get is a generic error. Once I step out of ExecuteResult() I don't know what happens; I'm right back to the beginning, as if I hadn't pressed the button.

Comment: What I mean by did the error happen on Facebook side is: when I configured my Facebook application, when the MVC site redirected to Facebook, Facebook displayed an error.  So if you are getting such an error, that's what I meant by did it OK on Facebook.  Otherwise, yes it probably is your application.  Out of the box, MVC 4 works with Facebook, so maybe you could go back to using the ExternalLogin approach and see if that works?

Comment: Yeah, I don't get any such error from Facebook.  (I can get that error with the non-mobile MVC web app, though.)  It never seems to make it over to the Facebook side.

The effect of clicking on that button is simply an error that flashes on the screen which says, "Error displaying page".